# Change WinForms application language at runtime

Tags: winforms, localization, runtime

It is possible to change the language of a localized WinForms application at runtime? I tried using the method described here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=174 but for example the control tooltips are not refreshed. I'm sure that I might face other problems too.

Is there any safe (0 bugs) way to do it?

Comment: Your ToolTip values are in a .resx?

Answer (score 2):

Guy Smith-Ferrier wrote the book on .NET internationalization (literally), and here is the code for his solution: http://www.dotneti18n.com/Downloads.aspx

In my experience it doesn't work perfectly, failing on DevExpress controls for example.